# Activate a ng-class from a controller to expand a menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, submenu, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

Menu with sub-menus that you can expand and highlight the chosen KPI.

```
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in kpis | groupBy: 'Type'" ng-class="{'active-menu-item': menu.active, 'open': menu.open}">
            <a ng-click="menu.open = !menu.open">
                <span ng-class="kpiInitializer.IconFromKpiType(key)"></span>{{kpiInitializer.TextFromKpiType(key)}}
            </a>
            <ul class="navbarColorOnClick submenu">
                <li ng-repeat="kpi in value" ui-sref-active="active">
                    <a ui-sref="kpi.overview({kpiChoice: '{{kpi.Id}}'})">{{kpi.Name}} </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

As you can se I have a sub-menu that can expand. `ng-click="menu.open = !menu.open`. It works fine but now I have a problem.

I want this submenu to expand when I click on a button in a controller that have nothing to do with this view. The right submenu should fall down. In this solution, it highlights the right property but the sub-menu dosen't expand so you cant see the highlighted choice.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had a similar issue with bootstrap, it was caused by nested li - ul - li tags. You will probably need to change it to div - ul - li.

Comment: Right now I have it like `<div><ul> <li> <ul> <li> <closetags....>` so how do you mean?
Should I remove the `<ul>` thats inside the `<li>` ?

Comment: You can't have <ul> inside of <li> that's what i mean